# How Do I Combine Views (UI)?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Since I'm a little weak with Javascript and still learning Angular.
I'm having trouble trying to combine a couple of UI's, not all at once of course.
Let me explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a sidemenu and I want to add a swipe card page when I tap on the swipe page in my menu. See my image below.
[image]

Having problem wrapping my head around how Angular does things, so any pointers & tips would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://codepen.io/andrewmcgivery/pen/bqEeI

Basically, to mix the two together, the ion-pane that contains the page of the swipe cards has to be in an ion-view.

```
<ion-view title="Welcome">
 <ion-pane ng-controller="CardsCtrl">

  <swipe-cards on-card-swipe="onSwipe($event)">

  <swipe-cards>
    <swipe-card on-card-swipe="cardSwiped()" id="start-card">
      Swipe down for a new card
    </swipe-card>
    <swipe-card ng-repeat="card in cards" on-destroy="cardDestroyed($index)" on-card-swipe="cardSwiped($index)">

      <div ng-controller="CardCtrl">
        <div class="title">
          {{card.title}}
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img ng-src="{{card.image}}">
        </div>
        <div class="button-bar">
          <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="goAway()">Answer</button>
          <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="goAway()">Decline</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </swipe-card>
  </swipe-cards>
</ion-pane>
```

Comment: Yeh, that's it, you're the only one get what I mean. I'll look over the coding on it and configure it so that the swipable page is in the listing and not as the main page. Again thank you!

Comment: Originally, I had errors in my js file trying to combine the swipable and others.

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks for reaching out to me on my blog and twitter.  Please be sure to mark my answer as the accepted answer! :)